# virtualenv and 'python -S' issue

Tags: python, python-2.7, virtualenv

Look at this log:

This works:

```
$ python -c 'import Queue'
$ python -S -c 'import Queue'
```

But not with virtualenv:

```
$ virtualenv v1
$ source v1/bin/activate
(v1)$ python -c 'import Queue'
(v1)$ python -S -c 'import Queue'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named Queue
```

Same story with `zipfile`, `argparse`, `optparse`, `shutil`, `subprocess`, `urllib`. On the other hand, bunch of system libraries are working (`os`, `datetime`, `sys`, `stat`, `re`).

I experienced it on OS X "brewed" python, and also on linux and windows (tried only `optparse`, sorry).

Is it a bug of virtualenv?

**UPDATED:** I also tried `virtualenv --system-site-packages` with the same result.

**UPDATED:** If you think it's not bug, tell why? Particularly, why I lose `subprocess` with `-S` option and don't lose `datetime`? What is so special about half of the modules?

Comment: @Carpetsmoker yeah, it's only reproducing with virtualenv. Updated the question. Thanks.

Comment: Did you use the [--system-site-packages](https://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/virtualenv.html#the-system-site-packages-option) option when you created the virtualenv? To me, its not surprising that `"-S     Disable the import of the module site and the site-dependent manipulations of sys.path that it entails."` means that some modules aren't importable.

Comment: @tdelaney yes, I did, and it didn't help. I mean absolutely the same result.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a bug of virtualenv. You're getting the error message because of the -S option after `python` in `python -S -c 'import Queue'` when it is used in the virtualenv Python virtual environment.

```
-S     Disable the import of the module site and the site-dependent
       manipulations of sys.path that it entails.
```

The [site](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/site.html) module is automatically imported during initialization. The automatic import can be suppressed using the python interpreter's -S option. Importing this module will append site-specific paths to the module search path and add a few builtins, unless -S was used.

Regarding your question about why you lose subprocess with -S option and don't lose datetime:  The difference is that datetime is a built-in module in Python and Queue is not. If you check in your vi folder, you will find that python is already installed in vi/bin/python (by virtualenv in Linux). However Queue is not installed anywhere in vi or its subdirectories unless you installed Queue locally in vi (e.g. with pip install).

Comment: It seems you have restated my question and copy-pasted docs. But it doesn't answer the question. Why it is not a bug? For instance, what is the difference between datetime and subprocess. Why I lose subprocess with ```-S``` option and don't lose datetime?

Comment: Actually the majority of modules are not built-in, so I don't think that built-in-ness affects the issue...

```
>>> sys.builtin_module_names
('__builtin__', '__main__', '_ast', '_codecs', '_sre', '_symtable', '_warnings', '_weakref', 'errno', 'exceptions', 'gc', 'imp', 'marshal', 'posix', 'pwd', 'signal', 'sys', 'thread', 'xxsubtype', 'zipimport')
```

Comment: The datetime module is written in C, and therefore datetime.__file__ points to an .so file (there is no datetime.__file__ on Windows), and therefore, you can't see the source. However the datetime module is there anyway (in Linux) in your Python virtual environment in `vi/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/datetime.x86_64-linux-gnu.so`.

Comment: The system python and virtualenv python seems to interpret -S differently. In other words, their lists of built-in modules differ (by a very large degree). Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The root cause is that virtualenv's list of built-in modules is much smaller than the system python's list.

The problem occurs with `optparse`, `subprocess`, and many other "built-in" (or so we thought) modules as well.

Read more here: http://tanin.nanakorn.com/blogs/362. The explanation is long.

Comment: But why some modules were not copied/symlinked? It seems this set of modules is hard-coded, see REQUIRED_MODULES in https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/blame/master/virtualenv.py

Comment: Well, REQUIRED_MODULES was here from the very beginning: https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/blob/37c3fa46a54c5558ddc11bd95db1932d170ab439/virtualenv.py Guess nobody bother to update it :)

Comment: Since Python 2.7 has been abandoned, it doesn't surprise me nobody is bothered enough to fix virtualenv in Python 2.7. Thank you for pointing to the source code. It's insightful.